# Git hook doesn't block binary files

Tags: git, perl

I've done a **pre-receive** git hook on the server side. It doesn't allow to push big files and doesn't allow to push binary files.

Here is a part of code, that has problems.

```
my @new_file_list =  `git diff --name-only $old..$new`;;
foreach $file (@new_file_list)
{
  $size = `git cat-file -s $new:$file`;
  print "!!! file $file";
  print "!!! size $size";
  chomp($file);

  # Check if file is binary
  if (-B $file)
  {
    print STDERR "ERROR: $file is binary.\n";
    print STDERR "Please check with repo owner before committing binary files.\n";
    print STDERR "To bypass this warning re-run your commit with the '--no-verify' option\n";
    exit 1;
  }

  # Check if file is too large
  if ($size > $limit)
  {
    my $hsize = hsize($size);
    my $hlimit = hsize($limit);
    print STDERR "ERROR: $file is greater than $hlimit bytes. Size of file is $hsize\n";
    print STDERR "Please check with repo owner before committing very large files.\n";
    print STDERR "To bypass this warning re-run your commit with the '--no-verify' option\n";
    exit 1;
  }
}
```

Check for size limit works well, but it doesn't block binary files at all. Could you tell, what is wrong in my code. Thanks.

Here is an output

```
remote: !!! file Chrysanthemum.jpg
remote: !!! size 879394
remote: !!! file Koala.jpg
remote: !!! size 780831
```

Comment: does `-B` test work on your binary file normally?

Comment: Does `-e $file` work? I'm thinking that `$file` might not be the full path to the file.

Comment: Dave Cross, yeah, looks like it. how can i make it work properly?

Answer (score 1):

See [Is there a git hook which can prevent binary check-ins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226132/is-there-a-git-hook-which-can-prevent-binary-check-ins) for examples of hooks to prevent binary files being checked in.

You're checking the file size in the new commit:

```
$size = `git cat-file -s $new:$file`;
```

but then making the binary check using the local filesystem:

```
if (-B $file)
```

You probably want this to be on the result of `git cat-file $new:$file` instead, using ([How can I read the output from external commands in real time in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236089/how-can-i-read-the-output-from-external-commands-in-real-time-in-perl)) something like:

```
open my $fh, '-|', 'git', 'cat-file', "$new:$file";

if (-B $fh)
{
    exit 1;
}
```

Comment: yeah, I got it. How can I make a check on the result of git cat-file $new:$file?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but an important comment.

```
`git diff --name-only $old..$new`
```

and

```
`git cat-file -s $new:$file`
```

suffer from a shell injection bugs. For example, consider what would happen if a file with a space were added to the repository.

Fixed:

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $cmd = shell_quote('git', 'diff', '--name-only', "$old..$new");
`$cmd`
```

and

```
my $cmd = shell_quote('git', 'cat-file', '-s', "$new:$file");
`$cmd`
```